# How can I get jquery roundabout to work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having a hard time getting it to work at all. I'm sure it's something simple but I can't figure it out. I have the file saved as index.html, I have uploaded to my FTP server along with my jquery.js file, and the roundabout files. I have them linked in my index.html file, with the unordered list and the stylesheet. But for some reason it displays the unordered list without the effect of the jquery roundabout.

Here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBD8q.png) of my code

Here is the [website](http://lustthetide.com/)

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to reference the jQuery library before any jQuery code.

If you hit Ctrl+Shift+J, you can see the error in the console.